# there is no error but still i cannot navigate to another page

Tags: flutter, navigation

when iam trying to navigate to anew page no errors occur but still nothing happens
i dont no if on tap is the problem or the void function , please help me
thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'meals_category_screen.dart';
class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  const CategoryItem(this.title, this.color);
  void  selectCategory (BuildContext ctx){
Navigator.of(ctx).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_){
  return const MealsCategoryScreen();
}));
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap:()=> selectCategory,
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(title,style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [color.withOpacity(.7), color],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try. `onTap: selectCategory` it might solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using `onTap: () => selectCategory(context)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer to your function to your onTap property, not calling your function.

For calling your function properly, you should do this:

```
onTap: () => selectCategory(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to passing the values like this

```
selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(CategoryMealsScreen.routeName,
    arguments: {'id': id, 'title': title});
```

}